# Custom equation numbering

Tags: equations, numbering

I want to label an equation

```
\[ 1 + 2 + \cdots + i = \frac{i(i+1)}{2} \eqname{Inequality(i)} \label{ineq} \]
```

involving the variable "i" as a function of (i) so the expected output looks like

> [LaTeX rendering of the above equation]      (2.4)(i)

(which actually means there are "i" such equations). The (2.4) might refer to Equation 4 of Section 2. When I access the equation later, I would like it to appear as

> Since Equation (2.4)(n+1) follows from Equation (2.4)(n), use induction...

(EDIT: Improved the wording to clarify the questions in comments. )

Comment: do you have problem if both (2.4) and (i) will be in parenthesis like ((2.4)(i)) or (2.4 (i)) and what do you prefer from these two?

Comment: Either is fine as long as the dependence on (i) is explicit. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand very well what all these numbers  are . Is (i) a number of a subequation (in which case 2 would be, say, a chapter number, and 4 the main equation number), or is a  certain group of equations numbered in roman, independently from other equations, in which case $2$ would be the chapter number and 4 the section number?

Comment: @Bernard It is the latter; the equation itself involves an "i". I have edited the equation to make it more relevant.

Comment: And `Big Math Equation`, I suppose, is just a shortcut for this post of the real maths stuff in the equation?

Comment: Yes that's right. For some reason, I couldn't get the Texed output there. In MathOverflow, $$ ... $$ works fine.

Comment: @AbhishekParab: See [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/5764)

Comment: I don't understand how the reference to `n+1` and `n` has anything to do with `i`. Why don't you just add these manually in the reference? Also, are you using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: @Werner It's probably some sort of inductive step - i.e., replacing `i` with `n` and so on.

Comment: @TheIncredibleZ1 is right, I can add manually in the reference but in the first instance when the equation appears, I need an "i" to denote the dependence of the equation on the variable / parameter "i". Hope that clarifies. Thanks all for your interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s see if I guessed correctly what you wish to get:

[image: Output of the following code]

This output was generated by the following code:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand*{\myTagFormat}[2]{(\ref{#1})($#2$)}



\begin{document}

\section{First}

Just to include a couple of equations:
\begin{align}
      1 &= 1 \label{eq:one} \\
    1+2 &= 3 \label{eq:two}
\end{align}
Until now, we have equations \eqref{eq:one} and~\eqref{eq:two}.

\section{Second}

Still another equation of the same form:
\begin{equation}
    1+2+3 = 6 \label{eq:three}
\end{equation}
Generalizing equations \eqref{eq:one}, \eqref{eq:two}, and~\eqref{eq:three}, we 
claim that
% Little trick:
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:base}% <-- Note!
\begin{equation}
    1+2+\dots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
    \tag*{\myTagFormat{eq:base}{n}}\label{eq:base-n}
\end{equation}
Now you can either:
\begin{itemize}
    \item
        reference equation~\ref{eq:base-n} directly (note that you must use
        \verb|\ref| instead of \verb|\eqref|, here), or
    \item
        say that equation~\myTagFormat{eq:base}{i+1} follows from
        equation~\myTagFormat{eq:base}{i} by adding $i+1$ on both sides of the
        latter.
\end{itemize}
One more equation to check that we haven't spoiled the numbering:
\begin{equation}
    x=y
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Using `mathtools` package command `\newtagform`, you can customize equations numbering in very detailed manner. The general syntax of the command is:

```
\newtagform{label}[tag format]{left}{right}
```

The `label` is just a unique ID for the tagging method which can be retrieved using the command `\usetagform{label}`, `left` and `right` are what should be written to the left and right of the tag (usually brackets). The `tag format` is the details of the tagging you want. In your particular case, you can use the following syntax:

```
[\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section})(\roman{equation})}]
```

After you setup new numbering format, you must also change how equations will appear when you reference them. For the style you want, the code should be:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section})(\roman{equation})}
```

Here is an example of how this custom numbering works:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
    \newtagform{Alph}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section})(\roman{equation})}]{}{}
    \usetagform{Alph}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section})(\roman{equation})}


\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}
\label{sec:one}

\begin{equation}
I = I_{ ph } -  
\overbrace{
    I_{ rs }
    \biggl[
    exp \biggl(
    \frac{V + I R_{s}}{a \thinspace V_{t}}
    \biggl) - 1   
    \biggl]
    % overbrace title
}^{ I_{d} }
-
\overbrace{
    \frac{V + I R_{s}}{R_{p}}
    % overbrace title
}^{I_{p}}
%
\label{eq:I_PV_m}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:R_p}
%
R_{p} = R_{p,ref}  \biggl(   \frac{G_{ref}}{G_{op}}  \biggl)   \biggl(  \frac{T_{op}}{T_{ref}}  \biggl)^{\delta_{p}}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
PMARE = \underset{i}{max} 
\biggl|  \frac{x_{i}-y_{i}}{y_{i}}  \biggl| \times 100\%
\quad i = 1, 2, \cdots , n
%
\label{eq:PMPARE}
\end{equation}


     A test for referencing Eqs. \ref{eq:I_PV_m}, \ref{eq:R_p}, and \ref{eq:PMPARE} which belong to Section \ref{sec:one}.


\section{Second Section}
\label{sec:two}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:R_{s}}
%
R_{s} = R_{s,ref}  \biggl(   \frac{T_{op}}{T_{ref}} \biggl)^{\delta_{s}}
\end{equation}


\begin{align}
I_{ph} &= I_{sc} \frac{R_{s} + R_{p}}{R_{p}}  \notag
\\
&= I_{sc,ref} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
\frac{G_{op}}{G_{ref}} \frac{R_{s} + R_{p}}{R_{p}}
%
\label{eq:I_ph}
\end{align}


    A test for referencing Eqs. \ref{eq:R_{s}} and \ref{eq:I_ph}which belong to Section \ref{sec:two}.


\end{document}
```

Other kinds of numbering options include `\Roman` (capitalized roman letters) `\alph`, and `\Alph`. Good luck

Comment: Actually what I wanted is somewhat different. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, with: `\newtagform{Alph}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section})(\roman{equation})}]{}{}
    \usetagform{Alph}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section})(\roman{equation})}` Works nice for me, I could customize the reference and the label.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understood the question in first reading, and I thought you want something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377478/how-to-number-automaticaly-a-family-of-equations-and-ref-to-them).

But It was not exactly what you want because my answer there can not give results like (n+1)... but if we change it a little bit we can have this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ifcounter[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi%
}%
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\newcommand\EqFamCustomTag[2]{%
\ifcounter{#1}{%
\expandafter\addtocounter{#1}{1}%
\xdef\temp{\csname #1 Eq\endcsname \space(#2)}%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #1\arabic{#1}\endcsname\temp%
\tag{\temp}%
}{%
\global\expandafter\newcounter{#1}%
\expandafter\addtocounter{#1}{1}%
\xdef\temp{\theequation\space(#2)}%
\xdef\eqonfamily{\theequation}%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #1 Eq\endcsname\eqonfamily%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #1\arabic{#1}\endcsname\temp%
\tag{\temp}%
\expandafter\addtocounter{equation}{1}
}%
}%
\makeatother
```

which can be used like this:

```
\begin{equation}
 \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3\cdot y^2}{10}=2\EqFamCustomTag{Elliptic}{n+1}
\end{equation}
```

and give you what you want... (I hope)... For automatic numbering in the other equations you have, you can use the one of my referred question-answer (This question started that too...)

Comment: Thanks but I found the solution by @GustavoMezetti easier to implement.

Comment: You are welcome... No problem @AbhishekParab... May be someone will look for automatic generated numbers and then will find mine useful too... It is good to have more than one solutions in the questions...