# How to automatically number an equation like this

Tags: equations, numbering

How to automatically number an equation like this:
[image]

Comment: Apparently, this is `subequations` environment

Comment: @ChristianHupfer... can I add regular equation between subequations? Sorry if the answer is easy... but did not found it yet...

Answer (score 10):

Not fundamentally different from GuM's answer, but some improvements to ease typing partial derivatives with `esdiff` and cross-referencing with `cleveref` (to be loaded *after* `hyperref`, if you use it):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}

\begin{document}

To find $g$, we know that
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \diffp{g}{x} & = 3x^2y^2 + x^2, \label{eq:1} \\%
    \diffp{g}{y} & = 2x^3y + y^2.\label{eq:2}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
Integrating \Cref{eq:1} with respect to $x$ gives us
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
  g = x^3y^2 + \frac{x^3}{3} + h(x)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You are worrying without reason: the coding is absolutely straightforward.  For example (see also [Christian Hupfer’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377967/how-to-automatically-number-an-equation-like-this/377994#comment936536_377967):

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}



\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2} % pretend we are in section two

By theorem~\ldots, \( \omega = dg \) for some~$g$.  To find~$g$, we know that
\begin{subequations}
    \label{eq:both}
    \begin{align}
        \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= 3x^{2}y^{2}+x^{2} \mbox{,}
                \label{eq:first} \\
        \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} &= 2x^{3}y+y^{2} \mbox{.}
                \label{eq:second}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
Integrating~\eqref{eq:first} with respect to~$x$ gives
\begin{equation}
    g = x^{3}y^{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} + h(y) \mbox{,}
\end{equation}
etc.  etc.  Note that you can also reference equation~\eqref{eq:both} as a
whole.

\end{document}
```

The corresponding output is

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Good answer. Years ago I had an agreement with a colleague: I typed her papers in TeX, but was free to change all her “w.r.t.” and “w.l.o.g.” into the proper “with respect to” and “without loss of generality”. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg `\newcommand{\wrt}{with respect to~}` ;-)

Comment: @sk8forether: … but do ***not*** try something similar with `\wlog`… ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for your remark!  Edited. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I created a way for something similar a few days before. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377478/how-to-number-automaticaly-a-family-of-equations-and-ref-to-them) it is.

Just dont forget to usepackage 'amsmath'

You can change it a little bit like this (not-tested):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ifcounter[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi%
}%
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\newcommand\EqFamTag[2][alph]{%
\ifcounter{#2}{%
\expandafter\addtocounter{#2}{1}%
\xdef\temp{\csname #2 Eq\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #2\arabic{#2}\endcsname\temp%
\tag{\temp}%
}{%
\global\expandafter\newcounter{#2}%
\expandafter\addtocounter{#2}{1}%
\xdef\temp{\theequation\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}%
\xdef\eqonfamily{\theequation}%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #2 Eq\endcsname\eqonfamily%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #2\arabic{#2}\endcsname\temp%
\tag{\temp}%
\expandafter\addtocounter{equation}{1}
}%
}%
\makeatother
```

Then you can write your equation like:

```
\begin{equation}
 x^2=3\EqFamTag{MyEquatioFamily}
\end{equation}
```

And the next equation with the same '\EqFamTag{}' will give you the next 
numbered equation in the same Family... you can add labels if needed or
not (check the above post to see how can refer to them without labels)

Answer (score 2):

When you are using plain TeX (it is not clear from your question) then you can use OPmac and you can define a variant to `\eqmark` macro called `\eqmarkx` with one parameter: the letter which must be appended.

```
\input opmac

\def\pdiff#1\over#2{{\partial#1\over\partial#2}}
\def\thednum{(\the\secnum.\the\dnum)}
\def\eqmarkx#1{\ifx a#1\global\advance\dnum by1 \fi
   \def\thednum{(\the\secnum.\the\dnum#1)}%
   \ifinner\else\eqno \fi 
   \wlabel\thednum \rm\thednum
}

\sec Test

To find $g$, we know that
$$ 
  \eqalignno{
     \pdiff g\over x &= 3x^2 y^2 + x^2, & \label[eq-a]\eqmarkx a \cr
     \pdiff g\over y &= 2x^3 y + y^2.   & \label[eq-b]\eqmarkx b \cr
   } 
$$
Integrating Equation \ref[eq-a] with respect to $x$ gives us
$$
  g = x^3 y^2 + {x^3 \over 3} + h(x) \eqmark
$$

\bye
```