# Customize subequation numbering

Tags: equations, amsmath, subequations, tag

I need to customize equation numbering as follows:

```
Some text ...

    a+b  (5)
    3+2  (5')

... some more text....

    c+d  (6)
```

The idea is that (5') is an example of (5). I thought of using subequations, but I am not sure how to customize the inner numbering, as it would generate 5a and 5b, or 5.i, 5.ii, etc.... If I use \tag{} instead, I am not sure how to get the previous equation number (5, in the example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define an `\eqorn` command. If you use `\eqorn['']` you get two primes; any math symbol can be specified in the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eqorn}[1][']{\tag{\theequation\ensuremath{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Some text ...
\begin{gather}% or align or whatnot
a+b \label{main} \\
3+2 \eqorn \label{secondary}
\end{gather}
... some more text....
\begin{equation}
c+d
\end{equation}
with references to \eqref{main} and \eqref{secondary}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very simple solution with which - as you say - any formula can be specified in the optional argument. Can it be modified so that the first equation in the series could also be customized (for instance, if I want three consecutive equations to be numbered as $(5_{x-y}), (5_{x+y}), (5_{z^2})$)?

Comment: @RW I'd say that `\eqorn[_{x-y}]` should work.

Comment: My question is not about typesetting a subscript - this part works perfectly OK, and this is a great advantage of your solution (compared to using the subequations environment). However, what I don't manage to do right is the "main" numbering. In my example, if add \eqorn just before the labels for the 2nd and 3rd equations, I get $(5),(5_{x+y}),(5_{z^2})$, but if I add \eqorn before all 3 labels I get $(4_{x-y}), (4_{x+y}), (4_{z^2})$ (the counter doesn't move), whereas what I want is $(5_{x-y}), (5_{x+y}), (5_{z^2})$. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @RW Not sure what you mean: if I open `subequations` and then make a `gather` environment with two equations having `\eqorn[_a]` and `\eqorn[_b]` respectively, I get `1_a` and `1_b`. If I then close `subequations`, the next equation is numbered 2.

Comment: Here is an example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eqorn}[1][']{\tag{\theequation\ensuremath{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{before}
c+d
\end{equation}

Some text ...
\begin{gather}
a+b \eqorn[a] \label{main} \\
3+2 \eqorn[b] \label{secondary}
\end{gather}
... some more text....
\begin{equation} \label{after}
c+d
\end{equation}
with references to \eqref{before}, \eqref{main} and \eqref{secondary}, \eqref{after}

\end{document}` However, you are right, this does not happen inside the subequation environment.

Comment: @RW If you have a new question based on the present answer, please make a new thread. Comments are not for solving related questions. Please, remove the above comments after you open the new question.

Comment: This is not a new or related question - I am answering your "not sure what you mean" and give an example showing that \eqorn command (which, as far as I am aware, is only described in your answer here)  does not work as expected. What do you mean by a "new thread" - a new "question" in the overflow terminology?

Comment: @RW That's fully expected. The `\eqorn` command uses the last previously established equation number. If you want to get `5<ornament-a>` and `5<ornament-b>`, use `subequations`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using `expl3`'s `\prg_replicate:nn` to produce `n` copies of `'` to number the equations in `subequations` and `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` to insert that in the `subequations` environment.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3}

% Creating a command to print a number of apostrophes
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \apost #1
  { \__andy_apost:cn { c@ #1 } }
\cs_new:Npn \__andy_apost:Nn #1
  {
    \ensuremath {
      \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { {'} }
    }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__andy_apost:Nn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Patching-in that command in \subequations
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\subequations
  {\def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}}
  {\def\theequation{\theparentequation\apost{equation}}}
  {}{\FAIL}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
  a+b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  3+2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  5
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly `\ensuremath{\prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 }{'}}` gives a better output.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is the modified answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377481/120578):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ifcounter[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi%
}%
\makeatother



\newcommand\EqFamTag[2][roman]{%
\ifcounter{#2}{%
\expandafter\addtocounter{#2}{1}%
\expandafter\addtocounter{#2Prev}{1}
\xdef\temp{\csname #2 Eq\endcsname \ifnum\value{#2Prev}>0 \space(\csname #1\endcsname{#2Prev})\fi}%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #2\arabic{#2}\endcsname\temp%
\tag{\temp}%
}{%
\global\expandafter\newcounter{#2}%
\global\expandafter\newcounter{#2Prev}
\expandafter\addtocounter{#2}{1}%
\xdef\temp{\theequation \ifnum\value{#2Prev}>0 \space(\csname #1\endcsname{#2Prev})\fi}%
\xdef\eqonfamily{\theequation}%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #2 Eq\endcsname\eqonfamily%
\global\expandafter\let\csname #2\arabic{#2}\endcsname\temp%
\tag{\temp}%
\expandafter\addtocounter{equation}{1}
}%
}%

\newcommand\myFamRef[2][1]{\csname #2#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{equation}
f(x)=3\cdot x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    x=4\cdot y \EqFamTag{MyFamily}
\end{equation}

As an example:

\begin{equation}
    x=4\cdot 2=8\EqFamTag{MyFamily}
\end{equation}

The equation: \myFamRef[2]{MyFamily} is the first example/member of the equation \myFamRef{MyFamily}

\begin{equation}
    x=4\cdot y 
\end{equation}

Another example of :

\begin{equation}
    x=4\cdot 2=8\EqFamTag{MyFamily}
\end{equation}

The equation: \myFamRef[3]{MyFamily} is the second example/member of the equation \myFamRef{MyFamily}

Another family of equations is:

\begin{equation}
    f(x)=3+y \EqFamTag{NewFam}
\end{equation}

and a member of it is:

\begin{equation}
    f(6)=9 \EqFamTag{NewFam}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to have a first (main) subequation numbered as an ordinary equation, the subequations standard numbering starting only at the second subequation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{equation}{4}

\begin{document}
Some text . . . . . .
\begin{subequations}
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\begin{gather}
  a+b \label{main} \\
  3+2 \label{ex-1} \\
  5\label{ex-2}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}.
. . . . . .Some more text . . . . . .
\begin{equation}
  c + d
\end{equation}

\eqref{ex-1} and \eqref{ex-2} illustrate \eqref{main}.

\end{document}
```

[image]