# labeling connecting equations

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

This is related to labeling an equation which is related or can be obtained as a consequence of the other.
Say I have equation, (1.1). How can I label two more equations related to that like, (1.1)', (1.1)''?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Consider providing an MWE, so others can see what you did so far. Plus, it makes it easier for everybody to just copy-paste and edit it.
Maybe these threads will lead you somewhere: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12026/label-equation-with-a-symbol ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377407/custom-equation-numbering/377482#377482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\tag` or `\tag*` to insert whatever you want for an "equation number":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = \mbox{First equation} \label{eq:first}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
  g(x) &= \mbox{Second equation} \tag*{(\theequation)'} \label{eq:second} \\
  h(x) &= \mbox{Third equation} \tag*{(\theequation)''} \label{eq:third}
\end{align}
See equations~\eqref{eq:first}, \ref{eq:second} and~\ref{eq:third}.
\begin{equation}
  i(x) = \mbox{Another equation}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`\eqref` inserts the surrounding `(`..`)`, so use `\ref` if you are managing the parentheses yourself. Some people use `(1')` and `(1'')` rather than `(1)'` and `(1)''`, allowing you to use `\eqref` as usual.

If the equations do not follow one another, you could use `\ref` instead of `\theequation`.

Comment: Thank you. I almost get I wanted, except the ' above, but I need that to be a "prime" as in derivatives.

Comment: @Fib1123: Try with `$'$`.