# About special numbering in equation

Tags: equations, numbering, mathtools

I would like to ask how to typeset the equation number like Charles's law in the picture? There is a `\circ` after the closing parenthersis. Do I need another package to do that? The packages that I am using are `chemfig`, `mhchem` and `graphicx`. Thanks a lot.

[image]

I am sorry that I cannot figure it out after reading [Custom equation numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377407/custom-equation-numbering/377477#377477). I would like to have the equation numbering like it in the picture.

```
\newcommand*{\myTagFormat}[2]{(\ref{#1})($#2$)}

\begin{flushleft}
Boyle's law
\end{flushleft}

\begin{align}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:base} 
pV &= constant,\text{ }at\text{ }constant\text{ }n, T\\
\tag*{\myTagFormat{eq:base}{n}}\label{eq:base-n}
\end{align}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377477/134144

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer to close the process of Q&A, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to suggest that you load the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package -- a superset of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package -- and use its `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` macros. (To revert to the default equation tags, run `\usetagform{default}`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\newtagform{Charles}{$($}{$)^{\circ}$}
\usetagform{Charles}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{section}
\setcounter{equation}{4} % just for this example

\noindent We assume that \dots
\begin{gather}
\textup{\bfseries Boyle's law: } pV=\dots \\
\textup{\bfseries Charles's law: } V = \dots \\
\hphantom{\textup{\bfseries Charles's law: }} p = \dots \\ 
\textup{Avogadro's principle: } V = \dots
\end{gather}
Boyle's and Charles's laws \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I would like to ask if there is code that only affect only 1 equation at a time but not the whole equation? As I still have some other equation that does not have `\circ` in the numbering.

Comment: @someone - Not sure I understand "affect only 1 equation at a time but not the whole equation". (Did you mean to write "...not the whole document"?) You could run `\usetagform{Charles}` and `\usetagform{default}` right before and after the "circled" equation in order to limit the scope of the "charles" tag form tp just that equation.